# PHP/MYSQL Compare Date this month and last Month

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a report module. I have worked on comparing this week and last weeks report for certain agents.

This weeks Report query is as follows

```
SELECT COUNT(created_at) AS cust_count_new, agency_id, created_at FROM customers WHERE 
(customers.created_at >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 DAY AND customers.created_at
< DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Last Week Report query is as follows

```
SELECT COUNT(created_at) AS cust_count_old, agency_id, created_at FROM customers WHERE 
(customers.created_at >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 13 DAY AND customers.created_at 
< DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 6 DAY
```

What I am doing is comparing this weeks and last weeks report. Now how can i change the query to this month and last months (30 days). I am little confused, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want 30 days from current date, or month corresponding to current date. Both are different.

Comment: Means if the run the report today. This month should be from 13-10-2018 to 13-11-2018 and last month should be 13-09-2018 to 13-10-2018

Comment: i think you should used start_date and end_date parameters that parameters get from user submit form.

Comment: There is no form involved here, this has to be a cron job which runs every month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MONTH` as unit in the [`INTERVAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals). Also, you can use [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) instead of `DATE(NOW())`, to get the current date.

This **Month** Report query will be:

```
SELECT COUNT(created_at) AS cust_count_new, 
       agency_id, 
       created_at 
FROM customers 
WHERE customers.created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND 
customers.created_at < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Last **Month** Report query is as follows

```
SELECT COUNT(created_at) AS cust_count_new, 
       agency_id, 
       created_at 
FROM customers 
WHERE customers.created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND 
customers.created_at < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```